# Sharing posts with ShareDialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to use the ShareDialog to share posts from a facebook page.
I can get a lot of data from the posts of the page. 
But I want to share it **as if the user was sharing on Facebook** itself so the "**share counter**" from the original post should be **increased**.

It works with posts of type : "**photo**". I use the "**link**" attribute from the post JSON to do it, works fine.

```
String link = post.getLink();
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder( this )
            .setLink( link )
            .build();
```

The problem is all other types:

- status - doesn't have a link attribute
- link - the link attribute is the shared link, not the link to the post. ie.: www.google.com

How can I make the Share Dialog work like this? Is there another way to share a post (increasing the share counter)?